# SSRS - Buttons are Misaligned in IE

Tags: printing, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS 2008R2 and my deployed reports were working fine. I am accessing these reports in another computer.

I am using IE to access these reports.

At first, I had the usual buttons --> Save As, Refresh, Print and Export to Data Fee
And I was able to print directly from IE using the Print button (not File-Print)

However, one fine day, the alignments of these buttons went from being horizontal to vertical. And the worse part is the Print button is now missing.

PS: I can't post photos. So imagine the buttons becoming vertically aligned and the print button missing. And I am using IE11

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Hayashi!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not thrilled about it, but have a look at this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511.aspx#bkmk_reportviewer

Under the table *Browser Requirements for Viewing Reports* there is a little note stating "Internet Explorer 11, add the report server URL to compatibility view in internet options".

I have tested this and confirmed that when we add our URL to the to IE11's Compatibility View List, the annoying display issues go away.

Not a server-side fix as I was hoping, but came straight from the horse's mouth.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the problem. My PC automatically updated my IE from 10 to 11.

Since then, this problem occurred. I went to uninstall IE 11 (from Control Panel) and revert back to IE 10.

Problem solved!

Hayashi

Comment: I'm chasing this issue myself but I don't think I can convince all our users to remove IE11.  If anyone has a server-side fix, please post.

Comment: @Michael12345 Any progress on this?

Comment: Someone from Microsoft has advised the SQL2012 SP1 CU8 fixes this:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/810527/sql-server-reporting-services-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11 At this stage there seems to be some doubt over whether it works with SQL2008R2. We haven't installed CU8 yet so can't verify.